# CD14538 and MC14538 are advertised as interchangeable, but one works on my board and the other doesn't

Tags: integrated-circuit, multivibrator, obsolescence

I am repairing a board that originally uses [MC14538](https://www.alldatasheet.fr/datasheet-pdf/pdf/11997/ONSEMI/MC14538.html) (dual monostable multivibrator) ICs. Since these are obsolete, I planned to use [CD14538](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd14538b.pdf)s, whose datasheet claims that the two are interchangeable.

However, when I place the CD14538, the board does not work, while with the old MC14538, the board works.

Schematic:
[image: Schematic]

I have checked the datasheets for both ICs and they are pin-to-pin compatible.
I have tried multiple CD14538 ICs (bought at different time) and the board still does not work. The board works perfectly with the original MC14538 ICs.

What could be the possible reasons why it doesn't work?

This is my first question here, please do not hesitate to let me know if I have done something wrong.

**EDIT :**

I ran some tests with a scope:

In yellow, the voltage across C1
In green, the voltage at the diode cathode
in blue, voltage across C2

[image: MC14538]
[image: CD14538]

**EDIT 2:**
I ended up buying a rail of CD4098 instead, and everything works fine without any changes (timings may need to be adjusted).
I don't mark this question as answered since we still don't knoẇ why it does not work.

Comment: You are wrong. Include a schematic.

Comment: In addition to schematics, you need to show what other parts connect to the chip. Saying you have an 10k resistor or 1n capacitor tells nothing, because for example there are different capacitor types in the same capacitance value and they have completely different properties other than the capacitance.

Comment: NB: they are perhaps "identical" but the wiring is not the same ... especially the timing "capacitors" (pins 1 and 15 of CD14538 are not "gnd" ? Although schematic seems to say?)

Comment: @SamGibson Thank you for your input. I asked around and discovered that HEF4538 was also used in place of MC14538 and CD14538. That would narrow the chances of a bug I guess ? Also, is such a bug likely, since this component is not _that_  complex ?

Comment: **Are** they interchangeable? The functional diagram of the CD145 does not have Pin 1 (Cx) grounded, but the MC14538 diagram and your circuit do. I've only spent about 30 seconds looking so I'm not sure the importance of that difference. Edit: Nvm it looks like the Cx pin is internally grounded in the CD145.

Comment: @InBedded16 Internal schematics are not "really" "identical" ...

Comment: @Antonio51 I didn't say that they were. I merely said that the one difference I spotted in the application circuits was negated by the internal circuitry of one of the chips. This question isn't about whether the chips are identical, but rather **why** one chip works in their circuit and the other does not.

Comment: @InBedded16 Ok ... My comment was just to highlight the fact that these circuits are "different" in their realization and "perhaps" also in their "operation" even if they are "identical" functions.

Comment: What are the R and C values/ranges?  Is the Q1 emitter grounded? Are the chip supply pins connected to +12V and GND?

Comment: @TimWilliams I just edited my post, sorry about forgetting these things. The trimmers are 0-200kΩ and set to about 100k. Q1 emitter is indeed grounded.

Comment: Note that "trimmers" (external value of Rx ) must be greater than 4k ... and 0< Cx < 100 uF for CD14538.

Answer (score 2):

Datasheet seems to say that MC14538 is "equivalent" to CD4528 (or CD4098).
From your datasheet ...

[image]

Although some are "identical, not have the same use.

[image]" ...

Update :
Can you verify "near" the box in red in the schematic?
Are the pins 1 and 15 of the circuit wired to "ground"?
If not, add a wire, and verify that the circuit works.

Schematic of the CD14538B

[image]

Comment: Where did you get that ? All i can find is that, in the CD14538 datasheet : "The CD14538B is interchangeable with type MC14538 and is similar
to and pin-compatible with the CD4098B and CD4538B. It can
replace the CD4538B which type is not recommended for new
designs."
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: In the datasheet of MC14538 ...

Comment: What you outlined in  the datasheet is about the **14528**, not **14538**. Sure it says that both are pin-to-pin compatible, but I don't recall ever mentionning 145**2**8 at all, did I? However my question is about the fact that the **CD14538** claims that it is __*interchangeable*__ with **MC14538**.


Sorry if my reply sounds harsh, it is not meant to be, and thank you for your time.

Comment: "Pin to pin" compatible does not say that it is "hardware" compatible, I think ... Anyway, this is mentioned in the datasheet of the MC14538B ...

Comment: Yes I do know that, but the **MC14538** datasheet does not talk about the CD14538. However, the **CD14538**'s datasheet says that they are __*interchangeable*__. For me, it means that not only are they pin-to-pin compatible but **also** behave identically and perform exactly the same operations.

Comment: Can you verify what I added in the answer update? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, pins 1, 15 and 8 are both internally and externally connected. (On both MC and CD 14538)

Answer (score 1):

I've got some TI CD14538 as well as the equivalent CD4098 on hand, 2022 date code, and can put together your circuit just to check if it will work.

You have a mistake in the circuit, though. The #R inputs cannot be driven with an RC reset circuit. You need to use a Schmitt trigger like CD4093 or CD40106, or one made from a CD4007, to pre-condition the reset inputs. Only the +T and -T inputs have Schmitt triggers.

I expect that if the physical circuit is as shown on your schematic, it was working by sheer luck only. The chip is used outside of its specs. That it works with MC14538 is nice, but shouldn't be expected, and I'd think it may stop working at some point if you'd test it across the entire temperature and operating voltage range. That's the downside of declaring a circuit "working" when it's used outside of specifications, but checked only at one VCC and at room temperature.

The !R input should be driven by a valid logic level, within the mandated rise- and fall time, as per the specs of the CD4000B family ([JESD13-B standard, free download](https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/docs/jesd-13-b)).

You may be also interested in these [CD4000 family reference cards](https://hackaday.io/project/191205-4000-series-logic-reference-cards) I've published on Hackaday, licensed [CC-BY-NC-4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/).

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'll check for that. I'd just like to add that I am not the designer of this circuit which has been in use for 15-20 years in multiple designs, but it sure as not seen very wide temperature range (17-25°C) nor wide Vcc range.

If you have time to replicate the circuit, I would be glad to here about your results, but please do not waste your precious time :)

Comment: I tried using a logic gate (CD4050) for the reset pin but it does not seem to change any things. I may have seen some activity on Q with your proper reset, but not ina reliable way. I'll try further later.
Your reference cards are very nice and I printed them to have them around !

Comment: @Jean :) I'm glad you found them useful. I use them for hobby projects and issue new releases whenever I find any mistakes.